# HTTP Error 400 Bad request calling api with python

Tags: python, api

```
list = [i for i in range(2321)]
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 100):
    my_list[i:i+100]
    query_get_data_by_dea_schedule = 'https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=dea_schedule:"{}"&limit={}'.format('CII', i)
    print(query_get_data_by_dea_schedule)
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(path_or_buf=query_get_data_by_dea_schedule, orient='values', typ='series', convert_dates=False)['results'])
    all_data_df = all_data_df.append(data_df)
```

I am trying to run this to get the data for 2321 lines that are coming from FDA for schedule 3 items. I need to read 100 at a time because that is the limit. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. Also, am I reading that right 100 at a time to save it in the data frame? It stops and gives me : HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request. thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been throttled by the API providers?

Comment: is that the issue ? I dont know

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: what do you try to do with `my_list[i:i+100]` ? It is useless.

Comment: maybe split code to simpler lines - ie. run `pd.read_json()` in separated line - and use `print()` to see for what values you get error.

Comment: instead of `list = [i for i in range(2321)]` you can do `my_list = list(range(2321))` but don't use name `list` as variable because there is function `list()`. Or write it even simpler `for i in range(0, 2321, 100):` because it makes no sense to create `range(2321)` to get later `len()`

Comment: I was suggesting a throttle causing the fda server to return http 4xx errors since I ran the code from an online pandas python editor without any issues.

Comment: @furas  I want to read 100 lines at a time and add it to the data frame. am I doing that with range(0, 2321, 100) ?

Comment: `range(0, 2321, 100)` is OK. But I don't know this API - normally in other APIs `limit` is always the same (ie. `100`) and they use variable like `start` or `offset` which should get different values from `range(0, 2321, 100)` - ie. `limit=100&offset=0` `limit=100&offset=100` `limit=100&offset=200`, etc.

Comment: based on [documentation](https://open.fda.gov/apis/query-parameters/) you should use `skip` for this `limit=100&skip=0` `limit=100&skip=100` `limit=100&skip=200`, etc.

Comment: @LoveenDyall interesting then it might be something in my computer ?

Comment: as for me problem is not computer but you use wrong values - you have to use `skip`, not `limit`

Comment: @furas then it will be query_get_data_by_dea_schedule = 'https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=dea_schedule:"{}"&skip={}'.format('CII', i)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://open.fda.gov/apis/query-parameters/) you should use `skip` instead of `limit` - and use always `limit=100` - like `limit=100&skip=0`, `limit=100&skip=100`, `limit=100&skip=200`, `limit=100&skip=300`, etc.

Minimal code which works for me:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=dea_schedule:"{}"&limit={}&skip={}'
all_data_df = []

limit = 100
for skip in range(0, 2321, limit):
    query = url.format('CII', limit, skip)
    print('query:', query)
    data = pd.read_json(query, orient='values', typ='series', convert_dates=False)
    data = data['results']
    all_data_df.append(data)
    
print(all_data_df)
```